# Method save does not exist use get()

Tags: php

```
 public function postMoviesEdit( MoviesEditRequest $request, $id){
    $episode= episode::where('movies_id', $id)->get();
    $episode->ep_quality   =   $request->txtQuality;
    $episode->ep_url       =   $request->txtFull;
    $episode->updated_at   = new DateTime();
    $episode->save();
```

I get that message: Method save does not exist.
I used the get () method instead of using first (). I want to get more than one result, so I used the get () method. Is there a way to fix it? Kindly help me so i can get more of a result

Comment: where is that class `episode` coming from? Sounds like a framework you should mention in your question/tags.